# symfony2 doctrine multiple update / transaction

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions

I'm working on a Symfony2 project with doctrine and have some problems with a SQL update. I have a database table where all entries have a position attribute, since the order is important and changeable by the customer. Finally, I decided to save the position as simple integer values, without any implemented logic, and update any affected rows.

So, I wrote this function

```
public function swapCookingStepAction($recipeId, $posBefore, $posAfter) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $swappedEntry = $em->getRepository('BarraFrontBundle:CookingStep')->findOneBy(array('recipe'=>$recipeId, 'position'=>$posBefore));
    $swappedEntry->setPosition($posAfter);

    if ($posBefore < $posAfter)
        $steps = $em->getRepository('BarraFrontBundle:CookingStep')->decreaseBetweenPos($recipeId, $posBefore+1, $posAfter);
    else
        $steps = $em->getRepository('BarraFrontBundle:CookingStep')->increaseBetweenPos($recipeId, $posAfter, $posBefore-1);

    $em->flush();
    return new Response("ok?");
}
```

and this repository with doctrine

```
class CookingStepRepository extends EntityRepository {
public function increaseBetweenPos($recipeId, $posBefore, $posAfter)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->update()
        ->set('c.position', 'c.position +1')
        ->where('c.recipe = :recipeId')
        ->andWhere('c.position BETWEEN :posBefore AND :posAfter')
        ->setParameter('posBefore', $posBefore)
        ->setParameter('posAfter', $posAfter)
        ->setParameter('recipeId', $recipeId)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}

public function decreaseBetweenPos($recipeId, $posBefore, $posAfter)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->update()
        ->set('c.position', 'c.position -1')
        ->where('c.recipe = :recipeId')
        ->andWhere('c.position BETWEEN :posBefore AND :posAfter')
        ->setParameter('posBefore', $posBefore)
        ->setParameter('posAfter', $posAfter)
        ->setParameter('recipeId', $recipeId)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}}
```

The queries are build as wished but unfortunately I get this primary key error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE CookingStep SET position = position - 1 WHERE recipe = ? AND (position BETWEEN ? AND ?)' with params ["6", 2, "2"]:

Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-6' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

for params (6, 1, 2). I tried to work with a transaction but this didn't change anything.

Could you help me, guys?

**UPDATE**
Just added a 4th parameter at the repository function and could remove the 2nd function.
If I change the primary key for tests, the code & update works very well.

Comment: Your issue seems to be caused by a composite primary key (the "1-6" duplicate looks like it). I'd guess your PK is [recipe, position], and there's already this recipe #6 registered for position 1. Maybe your DB table has some lingering entries from previous tests?

Comment: yes, recipe and position should build the PK. i would need a transaction to switch both entries at once, but i couldn't solve this.